# Can MS Blend 3&4 open a solution containing mixed code?

Tags: c#, c++, command-line-interface, expression-blend-4, expression-blend-3

I would like to know if Microsoft expression Blend can open up solutions made up in Visual Studio that contain parts of which are CLI, C# and C++ ? More specifically can one work with the solution in Blend only in the C# part and if so, is it able to build the solution and deliver a working exe & libs ? Does debugging the other parts work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blend does not like mixed projects -- they won't build and the design surfaces stop working.  And if that didn't kill it for you, Blend does not support solution folders (it just strips them right out and flattens everything).  You generally work with a project in Blend and work with the solution in Visual Studio.

Supposedly this might get better with WinRT and Windows 8, but I'm not holding my breath.

Comment: so basically there's no way of bridging the two ? In the sense that I would like to have the gui project blend(able) and the rest (datamodel, interfaces, business logic) in visual studio, while keeping the gui project a bridge between the 2, so that both developers and designer, work with blend on gui, while developers work exclusively on the others.

Comment: In this case, I don't think there is a good clean way to bridge the two.  CLI has been a red headed step child for a while now.  This is just another case of that same attitude from Microsoft (IMO).

Comment: thanks. I will take this as the answer. However, to workaround the broken designer, I found out that adding this line to your csproj file helps:<ProjectGuid>{C9319776-9508-438A-9365-F0584BC7B044}</ProjectGuid>. When adding it it enables the broken designer back. Will dig more into this.